# Create a keystore file (.jks) and a self signed certificate (.cer/.crt) in Java

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, jks

I want to create a keystore file (.jks) and a self signed certificate (.cer/.crt) in Java. I am trying this with :

Generate the keystore :

```
protected void getKeyStore(X509Certificate certificate)
{
    File newSnKeyStoreFile = new File("Mypath..\\keyStore.jks");

    try {

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keyStore.load(null, null);

        if(!certificate.toString().isEmpty())
        {
            keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream(newSnKeyStoreFile), "password".toCharArray());
            if (keyStore.getCertificateAlias(certificate) == null) {
                keyStore.setCertificateEntry("cert"+ count++, certificate);
            }
        }
        keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream(newSnKeyStoreFile), KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());

        // Write to .jks file
        BufferedWriter out = null;
        try {
            out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newSnKeyStoreFile));
            out.write(keyStore.toString());
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if ( out != null ) out.close();
        }
    }catch(Exception ke){
        System.out.print("Error occurred while setting up keyStore: " + ke.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I generate the certificate :

```
protected X509Certificate genCertificate()
{
    try {
        //Generate self signed certificate
        CertAndKeyGen gen = new CertAndKeyGen("RSA", "SHA1WithRSA")
        gen.generate(1024);
        X509Certificate cert = gen.getSelfCertificate(new X500Name("CN=ROOT"), (long) 365 * 24 * 3600);

        File certFile = new File("Mypath..\\Cert.cer");
        // Write to .cer file
        BufferedWriter out = null;
        try {
            out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(certFile));
            out.write(certificate.getEncoded().toString());
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if ( out != null ) out.close();
        }
        return cert;

    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now when I run this, the .jks and .cer files are created but when I try to check the keystore with cmd command I get the error :

Command - `keytool -list -keystore keyStore.jks`

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
```

and

Command - `keytool -printcert -v -file Cert.cer`

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Empty input
java.lang.Exception: Empty input
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.printCertFromStream(KeyTool.java:2234)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doPrintCert(KeyTool.java:2423)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:1069)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:340)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:333)
```

Any pointers about where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void getKeyStore(X509Certificate certificate)
{
    File newSnKeyStoreFile = new File("Mypath..\\keyStore.jks");

    try {

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keyStore.load(null, null);

        if(!certificate.toString().isEmpty())
```

This test is pointless. If you have a certificate, its string representation won't be empty. If you don't, you shouldn't be calling this method at all. Remove.

```
        {
            keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream(newSnKeyStoreFile), "password".toCharArray());
```

Why? There's nothing in it yet. Remove.

```
            if (keyStore.getCertificateAlias(certificate) == null) {
                keyStore.setCertificateEntry("cert"+ count++, certificate);
```

And if it isn't null you should either overwrite the entry anyway or throw an exception, instead of silently ignoring the condition.

```
            }
        }
        keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream(newSnKeyStoreFile), KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
```

Very good but you need to close this `FileOutputStream`.

```
        // Write to .jks file
        BufferedWriter out = null;
        try {
            out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newSnKeyStoreFile));
            out.write(keyStore.toString());
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if ( out != null ) out.close();
        }
```

Remove all this pointless junk. You've already stored the keystore. All you're accomplishing here is corrupting it.

```
   File certFile = new File("Mypath..\\Cert.cer");
    // Write to .cer file
    BufferedWriter out = null;
```

Wrong. A certificate file is binary. Use a `FileOutputStream.`

```
    try {
        out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(certFile));
```

Wrong, see above. `out = new FileOutputStream(certFile);`

```
        out.write(certificate.getEncoded().toString());
```

Wrong again. This should be

```
out.write(certificate.getEncoded());
```

You seem to have a mania for converting things to Strings. Try to taper off.

Comment: Thanks for the response. About `Remove all this pointless junk. You've already stored the keystore. All you're accomplishing here is corrupting it.` just adding the cert to keystore object will update my .jks file?

Comment: Well to answer my above comment, yes it did. Thank you for the answer, I will clean my code :)

Comment: Just adding the certificate to the KeyStore object will update the KeyStore object. Storing it to a file will update the file. Storing to the file a second or third time with the wrong code either does nothing or corrupts it.

Comment: Another issue here I am facing is, the .jks file contains only 1 certificate, how to open the existing jks and add new cert to it so that many entries can be held in same file?

Comment: Instead of loading `null, null` load it from an input stream connected to the existing file. It's hard to see why you're writing code for this at all when the keytool already exists.

Comment: Yes that worked. Well I am trying to understand how ssl handshake and the whole keystore-truststore, certificates and all work. So doing it through java. I have already tried the process with the java keytool.